# chrome tts word event. works on Windows not on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app that uses the tts API. When i call `chrome.tts.getVoices()` all the voices returned on the chromebook list 'word' as one of the event types. Like in the image below.

[image]

The problem I'm having is that even though the chromebook voices report that they support the `word` event i am not getting them in the `onEvent` callback. All I am getting is the `start` and `end` events. When i run this app in Windows it works fine. I get all the events that the "native" windows voice says it supports ("word", "sentence", etc...)

I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on this ???

Comment: The latest version (36.0.1985.143) seems to have word events triggered but the charIndex is different from what I got on a PC. Specifically, word event charIndices start from 0 on pc and increment to the beginning of next word while on chromebook it starts from the end of the first word and increment to the end of the next word on every callback.